# Is a convex function $f$ with $ \mathbb{P}(\{x:\frac{f(x+t)+f(x-t)-2f(x)}{2} \}=0)>0$ for all $t$ always constant?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Let $U \subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be open, $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex function and $m_t(x):= \frac{f(x+t)+f(x-t)-2f(x)}{2}$.
We may suppose that $U=(a,b)$ wehre $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup\{-\infty\}$ and $ b \in \mathbb{R} \cup\{+\infty\}$. Note that convexity of $f$ implies that $m_t(x)$ is non-negative.
Further, let $\mathbb{P}(A):=\int_Ae^{-f(x)}dx$ be a probability measure.

Denote $N_t:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}: m_t(x) = 0\}$ and suppose that $\mathbb{P}(N_t)>\frac{1}{4}$ for all $t>0$.

Is it true (and is there a simple way to prove) that $f$ is constant on $U$?

It seems to me that this should hold but I have not been able to prove it yet.

Thank you.

(edited the orignal question)

Comment: You mean - show $f$ is linear, don't you?

Comment: Yes but $\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-(mx+n)}dx = \infty$, if $m \neq 0$, so since $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure, linear $f$ would imply constant $f$.

Comment: It equals infinity even if $m = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample.  Let $f(x) = |x|$ on $U = \mathbb R$.  Then $m_t(x) = 0$ whenever $|x| > |t|$.  In particular, $\lambda(N_t) = \infty$.

Now to answer the new question.  I will do the case $U = \mathbb R$, otherwise you have to think about that $m_t$ means if $x+t$ or $x-t$ are not in $U$.

Since we have a probability measure, there exists $c<d$ such that $P(\mathbb R \setminus [c,d]) < 1/4$.  Therefore, for every $t>0$, there exists a number $x \in [c,d]$ such that $m_t(x) = 0$.  Since then $f$ is linear on $[x-t,x+t]$, by taking $t$ arbitrarily large, we obtain that $f$ is linear on $\mathbb R$.  (And being linear, $P$ isn't a probability measure, so $f$ doesn't exist.)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, thank you. However, my original problem was slightly more complicated and I wanted to simplify it for MSE by asking about $\lambda$ instead of a log-conave probability measure. I thought it wouldn't matter, but thanks to you I see that it does. I've edited the question. Is the hypothesis true now?

Comment: Ah thank you. The only thing I don't I understand is why do you need the interval $[c,d]$ in your proof. Where is the benefit in saying $x \in [c,d]$ instead of just $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Because then $t$ can get arbitrarily large, but $x$ could go to plus or minus infinity, so you can't guarantee that all of $\mathbb R$ is covered.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to extend this result to $\mathbb{R}^n?$ Say now we have a vector $v$ and $m_{v,t}(x):= \inf_{\langle u,v \rangle = t} \frac{f(x+u)+f(x-u)-2f(x)}{2}$.
I've tried to solve this analagous to your proof in $\mathbb{R}$ and I got to the point that $f$ is linear on the set $\{x+\lambda u \:;\: \lvert \lambda \rvert \leq 1\}$. However, taking $t$ arbitrarily large doesn't seem to help me here because that might change $u$.